# Is my bootstrap modal window loading my image even if I don't open it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a thumbnail gallery that displays thumbnail images and displays a modal window pop up when I click on the thumbnail. I'm not sure if this model window code is in the right place. My question is - is the modal ALWAYS loading the image when the page renders or just when I open the modal? Question 2 - should I have modal code for each thumbnail (like below) or should I place the modal code in one place and set the image with jquery? Please advise! Thanks.

Here is my html code that displays the thumbnail list

```html
<div id="row">
                <div id="sortable">
                    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
                    {
                        @*<li>this is an image</li>*@
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                @{
                                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail);
                                    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
                                 }
                                <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                    <img src="@imgSrc" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
                                </a>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                                    <p>...</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            @{
                                                var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image);
                                                var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
                                            }
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                                <img src="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="255" height="255" />
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: No. Images won't be loaded unless the image and it's parents are visible on the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, the image won't load until the modal is visible. But I wouldn't add a new modal for every image. The modal should be at the bottom and it's content dynamically loaded.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/3v3c5m1j/

Comment: how come I see the data in the image src then?